# Como imprimir o nome do método, do arquivo e da linha que foi chamada?

Tags: c#, .net, método

Exemplo:

nome do arquivo: `teste.cs`

Uma parte do código:

...

```
public void MeuMetodo()
{
    // suponha que essa linha seja a 100
    Console.WriteLine("Arquivo: " + arquivo + "Metodo: " + metodo +" linha: " + linha);
    //Resultado seria: Arquivo: teste.cs Metodo: MeuMetodo linha: 101
    //
    //mais codigos
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a classe [`StackFrame`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

```
sf.GetFileName(), sf.GetMethod(), sf.GetFileLineNumber()
```

Se estiver um modo *release* estas informações não estarão disponíveis. Tem técnicas que podem ajudar, mas em geral não valem a pena,quase sempre só deve usar isto *debugando*.

Também pode criar um método assim:

```
public static void MostraMetodo([CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null) {
    WriteLine($"File: {sourceFilePath}, Method {caller}, Line: {lineNumber} ");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/CodePosition.cs)

Onde chamar este método é o que será mostrado. Veja a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Deve ter outras técnicas.

Comment: Da pra pegar o nome da class usando `this.GetType().Name` e o nome do método usando `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` pelo menos essas informações você consegue pegar em release.